# Double check on disabled property

Tags: jsf, richfaces, el

this is my first post, i'm new in Java and jsf, and this is my problem..

I have this portion of code:

```
<rich:select
    valueChangeListener="#{bean.valueChanged}"
    disabled="#{not bean.enabledEdition}"
    enableManualInput="false"
    value="#{bean.typeSelected}">
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{bean.listStatus}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="selectitem" render="selectError" execute="@this" />
</rich:select>

<rich:select id="selectError"
    disabled="#{not bean.ErrorActive}"
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{bean.listKnownErrors}" />
</rich:select>
```

Then, if you pick typeSelected = "Error" con the first select, the second one is enabled to select the actual error you want to chose.
My problem is, that i have a "read only" mode, and what i need is to have a double condition in the disabled property, something like:

```
disabled="#{not bean.enabledEdition}, #{not bean.ErrorActive}"
```

but looks like that won't work, it appears always active, any suggestion??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well.. this is awkward, i just needed the following:

```
disabled="#{!bean.enabledEdition or !bean.ErrorActive}"
```

I hope someone finds it useful at least!